# Get X records from complex LINQ query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How can I get 10 records from complex LINQ query?
I tried to put `.Skip(X).Take(10)`, but it doesn't work, depending on where I'm trying to take 10 it returns the full set of objects or nothing.

Setting `.Skip(X).Take(10)` at the end of the query doesn't what I'm looking for because of slow performance.

This is my query:

```
List<ReportReturn> report =  
    from var1 in context.Table1
    join var2 in context.Table2
        on var1.AccountID equals var2.AccountID
    join var3 in context.Table3
        on var1.AccountID equals var3.AccountID into all
    where 
        var1.SubAccountID == intSubAccountID && 
        // ...... and more conditions

    let actual = var1.Total.GetValueOrDefault(0)
    let Unique = var2.CountUnique 
    let Total = var2.Count

    // ........ and more helper values

    orderby var1.Date descending

    from final in all.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new ReportReturn {
        // ........................some property assigments
    };
```

Comment: You're not showing your query. The query you're showing would not produce a `List<ReportReturn>`.

Comment: I feel like your `into all` is early. Why is it before your `where` and `orderby` clauses? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, are you trying to skip `N` and then take 10 of the *parents* or of the *children*?

Comment: To clarify: So when you put it at the **end** it does work, but your performance is the issue or does it not work at all? In the case of performance you need to look at the sql generated an go fromthere...

Answer (score 2):

just writing

```
.Skip(X).Take(10)
```

will give you output in `IEnumerable<T>` type but yours is `List<T>` type.

So you should use

```
.Skip(X).Take(10).ToList()
```

in your case.